# Spring 3.1.1.Release. RequestMappingHandlerMapping Autowired issue

Tags: spring, autowired, wadl

I'm trying to add a WADL method to my Spring Web Service application.  I'm following the instructions on a number of pages/posts on the topic here and other help sites on the net.

However, my app keeps failing on the auto wire of the RequestMappingHandlerMapping.

The error is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'wadlController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping net.my.app.ws.thing.WadlController.handlerMapping; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I've done everything I can think of and search out even added:

```
mvc:annotation-driven
```

But the app was entirely annotation drive already, so that didn't seem right.

What else could I be missing?  Is it a problem with Spring 3.1.1?

Comment: Can you Show aus the code of the bean `wadlController`

Comment: It just say that you context doesn't contain `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, of course it should be by default, but if your `wadlController` (mvc:annotation-driven) isn't present in the `servlet-context.xml` it doesn't see that bean, because it is a different spring context.

Comment: I've posted a work around below.  I'm not sure how it could have been in a different context though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the top section of my controller.  I did get it working by auto-wiring the ApplicationContext.  However, I don't really like that solution.

```
package net.stuff.stuff.stuff;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ProducesRequestCondition;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;


import net.stuff.wadl.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/application.wadl")
public class WadlController  {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WadlController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/xml" })
    public @ResponseBody WadlApplication generateWadl(HttpServletRequest request) {

        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = ctx.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class);

        WadlApplication result = new WadlApplication();
        WadlDoc doc = new WadlDoc();
        doc.setTitle("REST Service WADL");
        result.getDoc().add(doc);
        WadlResources wadResources = new WadlResources();
        wadResources.setBase(getBaseUrl(request));

        if (handlerMapping == null) {
            log.error("handlerMapping is null in WadlController???");
            return null;
        }
```